# Slim Framework - map function

Tags: php, slim

I have never worked with Slim framework before and need to change the `$app->map` function for the disclaimer to not show an internal page on the current site, but to open a new browser tab to another site.

How can I make `current-site.com/disclaimer` to not open the existing internal page, but to open a new tab to `external-site.com/disclaimer`?

*EDIT:* I figured out that I can use `$app->get` with `$app->redirect`, but that would not satisfy the "new tab" requirement.

Comment: PHP/Slim can't open another browser tab. You'd have to do this in the client.

Comment: @Kaylined, I figured, as redirect is a server side function. So how would I handle this in a client? I can assume that I would need to add a jQuery function or something that will intercept the `/disclaimer` link somehow, and prevent the default functionality, and do the redirect that way - but I am not sure where/how to let Slim framework execute what I want to do.

Comment: Just use target="blank" on the <a> tag, that will open the new tab, and then route it however you want with Slim in the backend.

Comment: @Kaylined: brilliant. Thanks. That worked. Please post as an answer so I can accept it as the solution, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Slim nor PHP can open new browser tabs. This must be done in the client side. The easiest way to do this would be to append target="blank" to the  tag.

Once the link is being opened in a new tab, you would use Slim to route the request however you wanted.